# Should I use JSONP for something else than cross domain http request?

Tags: json, angularjs, jsonp

Indeed, I'm merely learning `angularJS`, which encapsulates Ajax calls into an object called `$http`.

`$http` has a `jsonp` property, for handling jsonp. That led me to try to discover this new thing that is a little different from `json`.

I came briefly to the conclusion that it should **only** be used for cross domain problems.
And I would like you to tell me if there are any legitimate use of `jsonp` inside a webapp that doesn't do cross domain requests.

What sort of problems could it solve inside a single domain application ? If any ?

Indeed, the background question is that I wondered if I should start using jsonp 'anytime' for handling ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic form of JSONP is simple, and it's worked since well-before AJAX was "a thing."

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = '/myapi/do.jsonp';
s.type = 'text/javascript';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

No feature-detection or cross-browser hacks required. It just works.

One might even argue that JSONP should *only* be used for same-domain (or at least "trusted") requests. Requests to external domains are best piped through a same-domain proxy and security-checked.